# Shipping Wine from Italy to the UK

Tags: italy, eu, alcohol, rome

I'm going to be in Italy in May, and unfortunately am travelling with only hand luggage. I would, however, like to take advantage of the opportunity to buy Italian wines at a good rate while I am there, which means I will need to ship the wines to the UK separately. Because the UK a member of the EU, and this wine is for personal use only, I do not believe that there is any additional excise or tax to be paid, regardless of how I get the wine from Italy to myself in the UK.

Are there any wine shops in Rome that would offer me this service as standard?

Comment: To the close voter: I think this is on topic. It looks to me like the relevant rule is that questions that are "eliciting list-style answers, suggestions or recommendations on a topic or place (unless VERY specific criteria is listed)" are banned.

I believe this question has very specific criteria.

Comment: I haven't yet voted to close, but it would help to get very specific about what kinds of wine you are after or the vineyard branding you would be looking for.

Comment: I can't give much information to you on that front I'm afraid. I assumed that any seller sufficiently large to offer such a service would probably maintain a range of wines from all over Italy.

Comment: [This might answer most of your questions](http://www.sfoodle.com/how-to-import-wine-to-the-united-kingdom-england-scotland-northern-ireland-and-wales/).

Comment: @Dorothy that's for a business importing alcohol for sale, not for a person importing a case of wine for personal consumption. I found some info at UPS (they have special packaging available!), but they also had a mix of information for business/private that I had trouble sorting out.

Comment: @mkennedy; true but I'm seeing similar duties on bringing in quantities. Here's another [resource that sells boxes for shipping wine](https://www.mbe.it/it/store-locator). Apparently, shippers (UPS, FedEx, DHL) may not accept bulk shipments because they are licensed to export/import.

Comment: Well for that matter there's a distributor in Gravesend that I have used for fruit who also imports wine. You may need a wholesale license or a VAT number however. I had to use my VAT.

Comment: The link doesn't really at all answer my question. Also the close reason is erroneous, I'm not asking about prices of anything.